# Shell Scrap Object Properties weirdness

Tags: windows

This is not a problem, just something I am curious of.

How come whenever the user creates a new shell scrap object and then goes into its properties and enter something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfiCg.png]

It says 'Microsoft Office' even though office of any sort was and never has been installed. Maybe somebody who knows how windows works better can explain this?.

Answer (score 0):

Because a [shell scrap](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/138275) is a [Microsoft OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) object representing a document fragment. OLE has a longstanding association with MS Office providing capabilities like the ability to Embed an excel document within a word doc as a static object, or Link a spreadsheet to the word doc, so that when the original excel file changes the word doc shows those changes.

To be honest, I've not encountered a .shs since Windows95, and then they only worked when you dragged document contents to the desktop. Not sure how you created one, but it makes sense that such old technology, especially something that digs as deep into windows components as OLE, would be kept around for legacy purposes, but hasn't been looked at in decades. Modern MS Office is nothing like it once was, back when MS provided a richtext editor for free on every system, and were generally less controlling about software licensing.

As a result, I think you are looking at a window that was merged from a very very old verion of Office, into the windows core, and most everyone just forgot about it.

Comment: So office used to come with windows? I thought just notepad, write.exe and mspaint came with it. (I copied an mspaint selection to the desktop). I do know that wordpad used OLE though

Comment: no, but at some point the scrap viewer (or a part of its parser code) was imported into the windows core package base is my guess. since you don't say what version of windows you are on, I can only suppose. OLE and the OleDB have become core portions of the windows desktop, powering the COM+ runtime, and its successors the MSVCRT and .Net. keep in mind the window you are seeing is the result of a single line of code like `MessageBox.ShowDialog("Microsoft Office", "The Value entered does not match the specified type..." ); ` [not real code] so its easy to see how it might have been overlooked.